# Cuando trato de realizar un consulta con MySql con muchos registros usando PDO, no me devuelve resultados

Tags: php, mysql

estoy creando un formulario en php en los que uso etiquetas select trayendo las opciones desde una base de datos con PDO.

El problema es que en la opción de "Nacionalidad" necesito traer 201 registros que son todos los paises desde una tabla y al intentar hacerlo, no me regresa los datos. Este es el código donde llamo la consulta:

```
<?php 
require_once "conexion.php";
class PaisesDao extends Conexion{
    public function mostrarPaises(){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id_pais,nombre_pais,nacionalidad FROM nacionalidades");
        $stmt->execute;
        $array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt = null;
        echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

La tabla nacionalidades tiene 201 registros. Intenté hacer la consulta con una tabla diferente con menos registros y me funciona normalmente, el problema se encuentra cuando ingreso el resto de los datos a la tabla. En lugar de mostrarme el json en la página, me muestra la página en blanco.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré mi error. Lo que estaba sucediendo era que una de las nacionalidades incluía una "ñ" y eso era lo que no permitía que se generara el json. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002822/pdo-and-utf-8-special-characters-in-php-mysql) encontré la solución para que el PDO me acepte consultas que incluyan caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
 $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->query("SELECT id_pais,nombre_pais,nacionalidad FROM nacionalidades");
```

usa `prepare` cuando ingreses una variable, `query` cuando la consulta sea estática

Comment: Vale, eso no lo sabía. Sin embargo el error persiste, he leído en la documentación de php algo sobre LOB, pero ahí dice que es usado para imágenes. ¿Sabes algo sobre eso?

Comment: intentaste quitar PDO::FETCH_ASSOC? y solo usar fetchAll(); yo he probado y funciona perfectamente para consulta de miles de registros

Comment: Sí, acabo de probarlo, pero no me funciona todavía. Nunca me había pasado. ¿No sabes si tendrá qué ver con el navegador o algo así?